# Function, Get timestamp for file in Linux Path

Tags: linux, excel, vba

I have a function to get timestamps of files that are local for which I provide a path.

```
Public Function GetFileDate(strFile As String) As Date


    Dim lastDate As Date
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FilePath As String

    FileName = Split(strFile, "\")(UBound(Split(strFile, "\")))
    FilePath = Replace(strFile, FileName, vbNullString)

    FileName = Dir(FilePath & FileName)

    Do While FileName <> vbNullString

        If lastDate < FileDateTime(FilePath & FileName) Then
            lastDate = FileDateTime(FilePath & FileName)
        End If

        FileName = Dir
    Loop

    GetFileDate = lastDate

End Function
```

My question is, how can I get the timestamps of files that are in linux(I have to log onto Putty or WINSCP to see timestamps). Lets say I can only view the files via WINSCP program and would like this function to work for some of these files. I have the path names.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a Samba Share which you are using to access the files? Then it should be straight forward. If you are using a third-party tool to access the files then Excel needs to access the API to make use of it.

Comment: Im using WINSCP to access the files. Not to sure about samba share.

Comment: Can you control either of these terminal programs programmatically? I. e. can you start them from your application, issue a command and read back the output?

Comment: No, I just use a a gui to view the timestamps. I just want to use a function to obtain these times in excel.

Comment: Looking at this site it seems that there is a WINSCP API which you can reference from within Excel: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_vb Go into the VBE and look for the corresponding library. Afterwards you could use early-binding to explore the various options you have to control the program from within Excel. If that's not an option then your question should be changed and (most importantly) the [Excel] tag and the [Excel-VBA] tag should be removed. But in that case I would also start wondering why you are posting on this site (which is for programmers, coding, errors, bugs, etc.).

Comment: A work around: simply bring the files local(using winscp) and then use the above function.  Even though this can be tedious i am not sure how to use the above function for files that are not local.